# Mouse drifts when clicking in Minecraft

Tags: mouse, minecraft

I am trying to play Minecraft Beta 1.7.3, every time I click and move the mouse at the same time, the cursor appears briefly and will unfocus from the game if the movement is large enough. I am using Java 8, Ubuntu 22.04, and MultiMC as a launcher. Please let me know what additional information I should provide.

The issue doesn't happen when I am in fullscreen, but I would prefer to be in windowed mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's OS-related. You should try to use a different mouse first, check if this changes something.